# How to use file content search from Windows 10 as fast as macOS Spotlight?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

I haven't used macOS, but I saw on a glimpse the other people using it and the search result from it was near-instantaneous, including the file content search. I think its name is Spotlight.

I use Windows 10 and wanted to use Spotlight-like search features, especially the fast file context search. I tinkered with Windows Search and its index settings, but it's still very slow.

I tried:

- Windows Search

  - Indexing Options

    - Include Locations for indexing. Only included specific folders I frequently use.
    - Checked the document types(txt, pdf, and so on) are set to index its file contents from "File Types". It was set by default.
  - File explorer

    - Turned off all checkboxes from "In non-indexed location" to boost indexed location search. No differences in performance were found.
  - Search from

    - Start menu(Win key + type search word): File contents are not being searched
    - File explorer

      - Unusably slow(maybe impossible?) if searched from the indexed folder's parent or higher folder
      - Near-instantaneous if searched from the indexed folder or its subfolders. This is the closest to what I want, but having to navigate to the folder to begin the search is tedious.
- PowerToys Run

  - It seems file contents are not being searched
- [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) v1.4.1.1015

  - Does wonders when searching filenames or other indexed properties, but lack of indexing file contents

How to use file content search from Windows 10 as fast as macOS Spotlight? I'm willing to use other tools if I have to.

Comment: How long are you giving it to complete indexing every time you make a change? Spotlight's initial index can take days to complete…. but yes, it's lightning fast once it's done.

Comment: @Tetsujin If it's about the individual file indexing time, maybe from 5 mins to 1 day, depending on the use case. If it's about the rebuilding index, maybe around a week?

Comment: Hmm.. OK. That would feel like plenty of time. idk how to speed it up on Win, I was just worried in case you were being impatient with it, but it doesn't seem like you are. Wish you luck.

Comment: Many years ago, I used Google Desktop Search (you can search on google to find it) it takes its time to do indexing and I found it faster than the default search in windows. You should give it a shot.